# Asynchronous append to .txt file in delphi

Tags: delphi, asynchronous, text-files

I'm trying to run a mail server and I want to keep track of the events like login, connect etc.. and I want to save this data in a log .txt file. But since it has to be done asynchronously I don't know how to lock the file for the current data append and then release it for next use. So basically I'm asking for help for a procedure called `asyncAppendToFile(fileName : String; textToAppend : String)`

```
procedure SMTPServerUserLogin(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext;
  const AUsername, APassword: String; var VAuthenticated: Boolean);
begin
  asyncAppendToFile(myFile, 'User ' + AUserName + ' attempts a login');  
end;
```

Comment: Do you want to call "asyncAppendToFile" in parallel from one application or from different applications?

Comment: @Fenistil From one application only - but for more than one ``SMTPServer`` events (not only UserLogin)

Comment: I personaly don't think that writing log into a file using asynchronus approach is a good idea. Why? Becouse doing so you probably won't be able to maintain the chronological order of events in the log file. So instead I would recomend you create some memory buffer which could store multiple log entries. Then at certain intervals you sort them in chonological order and then write those entries into log file.

Comment: @SilverWarior I don't really understand that comment. The events are asynchronous. They can be occurring at the same time. They themselves don't have an order.

Comment: @Roman_Bezjak Use a critical section or mutex to serialize the logging. Any good logging framework will already cater for the scenario. I'd recommend the Synopse logging framework.

Comment: Indy has the `TIdServerInterceptLogFile` component which you can bind to your `TIdSMTPServer`'s `Intercept` property and you'll get ready made logging for your server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From one application, you can make a queue and put the lines there. Then a Thread check for this queue and write to the log file the lines in arriving order.

```
TWorkerThread = class(TThread)
private
  Killed:boolean;
  ListLock:TRTLCriticalSection;
  Jobs:TStringList;
  JobEvent:TEvent;
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
  procedure DoJob;
public
  constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
  destructor Destroy; override;
  procedure AddJob(s:string);
  function  JobCount: Integer;
  procedure Kill;
end;

constructor TWorkerThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
  Killed:=false;
  InitializeCriticalSection(ListLock);
  Jobs:=TStringList.Create;
  JobEvent:=TEvent.Create(nil, true, false, 'jobs.event');
end;

destructor TWorkerThread.Destroy;
begin
  Jobs.Free;
  JobEvent.Free;
  DeleteCriticalSection(ListLock);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Killed or not Self.Terminated do
    begin
      EnterCriticalSection(ListLock);
      if Jobs.Count>0 then
        begin
          LeaveCriticalSection(ListLock);
          DoJob;
        end
      else
        begin
          JobEvent.ResetEvent;
          LeaveCriticalSection(ListLock);
          JobEvent.WaitFor(5000);
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Kill;
begin
  Killed:=true;
  JobEvent.SetEvent;
  Terminate;
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.AddJob(s:string);
begin
  EnterCriticalSection(ListLock);
  try
    Jobs.Add(s);
    JobEvent.SetEvent;
  finally
    LeaveCriticalSection(ListLock);
  end;
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.DoJob;
var f:textfile;
    s:string;

begin
  //Pick the next Job
  EnterCriticalSection(ListLock);
  try
    s:=Jobs[0];
  finally
    LeaveCriticalSection(ListLock);
  end;

  //Do the work
  assignfile (f,'server.log');
  append(f);
  writeln(f,s);
  closefile (f);

  //Delete from queue
  EnterCriticalSection(ListLock);
  try
    Jobs.Delete(0);  
  finally
    LeaveCriticalSection(ListLock);
  end;
end;
```

In Form Create:

```
Worker:=TWorkerThread.Create(false);
Worker.Priority:=tpLower;
```

In Form Destroy:

```
Worker.Kill;
Worker.WaitFor;
Worker.Free;
```

Usage:

```
procedure SMTPServerUserLogin(ASender: TIdSMTPServerContext;
  const AUsername, APassword: String; var VAuthenticated: Boolean);
begin
  Worker.AddJob('User ' + AUserName + ' attempts a login');
end;
```

Comment: It's normal and preferred to call inherited first in a constructor. Your Kill mechanism just reimplements Terminate. Better to piggy back on Terminate. Calling inherited in Execute is odd. You never want to do that, even though it does nothing it begs the question.