# Http client get requests

Tags: delphi, http, memory-leaks, indy, indy10

I created an HTTP server with Delphi. To test the server response time I created an http client application which generates random urls. The problem is when I start sending requests to the server part of them are being processed. Here is part of my code:

This procedure is being executed to start sending requests:

```
procedure TPerformanceTestForm.ExecuteURLs;
var
  requests: array of TRequestBuilder;
  i: Integer;
  Stopwatch: TStopwatch;
  Elapsed: TTimeSpan;
begin
  SetLength(requests, 10);
  EnterCriticalSection(criticalSection);
  Stopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;

  for i := 0 to Length(requests) - 1 do
  begin
    requests[i] := TRequestBuilder.Create;
  end;

  // remove this lines from source in order to execute all threads
  // for i := 0 to Length(requests) - 1 do
  // begin
  //   requests[i].Terminate;
  // end;

  Elapsed := Stopwatch.Elapsed;
  Seconds := Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
  LeaveCriticalSection(criticalSection);
end;

procedure TPerformanceTestForm.btnStopQueriesClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Length(requests) - 1 do
  begin
    // requests[i].WaitFor; // the program crashes
    requests[i].Free;
  end;
end;
```

This is part of TRequestBuilder class:

```
TRequestBuilder = class(TThread)
private
  fHttpClient: TIdHTTP;
public
  Constructor Create; reintroduce;
  procedure Execute; override;
end;

Constructor TRequestBuilder.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False); // in order not to start another loop and call start for each instance
  // FreeOnTerminate := True; // removed this line; see the first answer to know why
  Self.fHttpClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
  // HttpWorkBegin and HttWork I get from the first answer
  Self.fHttpClient.OnWorkBegin := HttpWorkBegin;
  Self.fHttpClient.OnWork := HttpWork; 
end;

procedure TRequestBuilder.Execute;
var
  request, response: string;
begin
  repeat
    try
      request := GenerateHttpRequest;
      response := Self.fHttpClient.Get(request);
      log.AddJob(request + ' ---> ' + response + ' ---> ' +
        FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss', Now));
      except
        on e: Exception do
        begin
        errlog.Add(FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss', Now) + ' ---> ' +
          e.Message);
        end;
     end;
  until (Terminated);
end;

// EDIT: change Execute procedure to avoid socket errors (removed the httpClient from class variables):
procedure TRequestBuilder.Execute;
var
  request, response: string;
  httpClient: TIdHTTP;
begin
  repeat
    try
      httpClient := TIdHTTP.Create;

      try
        request := GenerateHttpRequest;
        response := httpClient.Get(request);
        log.AddJob(request + ' ---> ' + response + ' ---> ' +
          FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss', Now));
      finally
        httpClient.Free;
      end;
    except
      on e: Exception do
      begin
        errlog.Add(FormatDateTime('dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss', Now) + ' ---> ' +
          e.Message);
      end;
    end;
  until (Terminated);
end;
```

**EDIT: ** When I stop the http client I get this error: Access violation at address 004083A0 in module App.exe. Read of address FFFFFFFC.

**EDIT: ** I removed the second for loop in ExecutreURLs and now the program works fine (sometimes the exception is raised). My question now is: is the program leaking memory when I don't terminate the requests in ExecuteURLs procedure?

**EDIT: ** When I remove the repeat- until loop from the Execute procedure the program works fine (only the exception in the first edit is thrown). When I add the repeat- until loop and remove from btnStopQueries onclick event I get several socket errors

Comment: What errors are you getting? You need to be more specific.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the error was in OnFormDestroy and I fixed it but I forgot to update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `TThread.Terminate()` merely sets the `TThread.Terminated` property and does nothing else.  It does not actually terminate the thread.  A thread is responsible for checking `Terminated` periodically and then exiting from `Execute()` when needed.  You are not using the `Terminated` property anywhere in your code, so calling `Terminate()` is useless in your example.

You are setting `FreeOnTerminate=True` in your threads.  So no, you are not leaking the threads by not calling `Terminate()`.  They will free themselves after `TIdHTTP` has finished its work.

Your Access Violation is most likely due to one or more of the threads simply terminating and freeing themselves from memory before you have a chance to call `Terminate()` on them.  The rule of thumb for using `FreeOnTerminate` is that if you need to access a thread object from *outside* of the thread's own code (such as you are doing by tracking the threads and calling `Terminate()` on them) then **DO NOT** use `FreeOnTerminate=True` at all!  The `TThread` object could disappear from memory at *ANY* moment.  Your only saving grace in that situation is if you use the `TThread.OnTerminate` event to be notified when a `FreeOnTerminate` thread terminates.  That event is fired before the thread frees itself.  Otherwise, leave `FreeOnTerminate=False` and manually free the thread object when you are done using it.

A safer approach would look more like this instead:

```
procedure TPerformanceTestForm.ExecuteURLs;
var
  requests: array of TRequestBuilder;
  i: Integer;
  Stopwatch: TStopwatch;
  Elapsed: TTimeSpan;
begin
  SetLength(requests, 10);
  Stopwatch := TStopwatch.StartNew;

  for i := 0 to Length(requests) - 1 do
  begin
    requests[i] := TRequestBuilder.Create;
  end;

  // optional, maybe after a timeout...
  {
  for i := 0 to Length(requests) - 1 do
  begin
    requests[i].Terminate;
  end;
  }

  for i := 0 to Length(requests) - 1 do
  begin
    requests[i].WaitFor;
    requests[i].Free;
  end;

  Elapsed := Stopwatch.Elapsed;
  Seconds := Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
end;
```

```
TRequestBuilder = class(TThread)
private
  fHttpClient: TIdHTTP;
  procedure HttpWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCountMax: Int64);
  procedure HttpWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
public
  constructor Create; reintroduce;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

constructor TRequestBuilder.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  fHttpClient := TIdHTTP.Create;
  fHttpClient.OnWorkBegin := HttpWorkBegin;
  fHttpClient.OnWork := HttpWork;
end;

destructor TRequestBuilder.Destroy;
begin
  fHttpClient.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TRequestBuilder.HttpWorkBegin(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCountMax: Int64);
begin
  if Terminated then SysUtils.Abort;
end;

procedure TRequestBuilder.HttpWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
begin
  if Terminated then SysUtils.Abort;
end;

procedure TRequestBuilder.Execute;
var
  request, response: string;
begin
  request := 'http://localhost/?command=validcommand&param=value';
  response := fHttpClient.Get(request);
  // log source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099961/asynchronous-append-to-txt-file-in-delphi
  log.AddJob(request + ' ---> ' + response);
end;
```

Comment: I made requests a global variable and I put the second loop for i := 0 to Length(requests) - 1 do
  begin
    requests[i].WaitFor;
    requests[i].Free;
  end; as an onclick event of another button but the program crashes. I also made some changes in the source (see the edited question)

Comment: can you take a look in the second Execute procedure: do I have to set OnWorkBegin and OnWork properties for the local http client (local for the execute procedure) with the procedures from your answer. When I set them there is a difference in the content of the log files (some queries with their responses are not written in the client log file)

Comment: You still have a local `requests` variable inside of `ExecuteURLs()`, you are not populating the `requests` variable that `btnStopQueriesClick()` accesses.  And you need to call `Terminate()` and `WaitFor()` on each thread before you `Free()` it. Never free a thread that is still running. And you do not need to recreate the `TIdHTTP` on every loop iteration. Create it once at the top of `Execute()` (if not in the constructor) and then reuse it inside the loop.

Comment: I changed requests to a global variable. The advice to create the http client is very useful, thank you. In what order should I call Terminate() and WaitFor()?

Comment: Obviously, you have to call `Terminate()` first, since `WaitFor()` blocks until the thread actually terminates.